# Set theory resources and order

Tags: set-theory

I have two questions (it doesn’t make sense that i should have to post two questions that are intrinsically related separately) both relating to set theory. The first of which is in what order are topics covered in set theory. The second is what are some good resources for studying set theory.

Comment: You can join the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2318/set-theory) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so firstly, assuming at the undergraduate level, you will be doing Set notations and partitioning(by which I mean using set notation to describe how 2/3 sets interact). Set notations with 2 and then 3 sets and how to apply these to venn diagrams. a good resource I use is wolframAlpha for showing how the notations checks out against venn diagrams; really useful. next you would want to apply these to Probability theory. Also try this book: Intro. to Set Theory by Weiss

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Study Guide](https://www.logicmatters.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/TeachYourselfLogic2020.pdf) -- §5.3 is on introductory-level set theory books, then §8.1 on more advanced books.

Still, you might have difficulty getting hold of those books with many university libraries closed in these troubled times (it is between you and your conscience whether you think is therefore OK to use a pdf repository ...). However, [Judith Roitman's introductory book](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~clarson/roitman-set-theory.pdf), one of the books listed in the TYL Study Guide, is freely available and might help.